# QLPreviewController NavigationBar barTintColor

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift4, qlpreviewcontroller

When I `self.present()` `QLPreviewController`, its `NavigationBar`loses the color, which was implemented in `AppDelegate`.

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Colors.fifth   // Blue color
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

`QLPreviewController` implementation:

```
let preview = QLPreviewController()
preview.dataSource = self

func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
    return fileURL! as QLPreviewItem
}

fileprivate func showDocument(fileId: Int) {
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    self.fileService.download(id: fileId) {
        url, error in

        if error == nil {
            self.fileURL = url
            if QLPreviewController.canPreview(self.fileURL! as QLPreviewItem) {
                self.present(self.preview, animated: true, completion: nil)
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            } else {
                SVProgressHUD.showDismissableError(with: "Произошла ошибка во время чтения файла \(url!.lastPathComponent)")
            }
        } else {
            SVProgressHUD.showDismissableError(with: error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to `self.show()` and its `NavigationBar` is **OK**!
I want to set `QLPreviewController's NavigationBar` color to have the same settings as `AppDelegate's UINavigationBar`. How can I change this programmatically? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First instantiate a **UINavigationController** and your **QLPreviewController** as its **root view controller**. Then you can present that navigation bar and that will have properties that you set in app delegate class.

```
    let preview = QLPreviewController()
    preview.dataSource = self
    preview.currentPreviewItemIndex = 0
    let navBar = UINavigationController(rootViewController: preview)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissQLPreviewController))
    preview.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = doneButton
    self.present(navBar, animated: true)
```